# Approval workflow creates several major versions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, version

In Sharepoint Designer 2010 we've created a library workflow with the following two lines:

If document changes, and field is "Yes", change the status approval to "Approved".

This workflow triggers when element in library has some change.

The workflow works as expected, and change the status to "Approved", but randomly, creates till 10 major versions of the document.

Obviously, this is not the expected behaviour. We haven't find any solution to this behaviour.

We've been working with Sharepoint 2010

Thank's in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your if condition to:

`If field is "Yes" and approval status not "Approved"`

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. Efectively, we forget to stop triggering the workflow if status is yet "Approved"

Comment: Changing status changes an element and triggers new workflow.